# C++ Expand class Base with class Derived that contains a function returning a * b from base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Base {
public :
Base ( int a , int b ) : a ( a ) , b ( b ) { }
protected :
int a , b ;
} ;
```

I have this class called Base, how do I create an inherited class Derived with a function that will multiply protected members a and b?

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << a * b;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base b(2, 3);
    Derived d;
    d.print();
}
```

This is what I attempted but I get error message ' the default constructor of "Derived" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Answer (score 1):

The error is because there's no valid `Derived` constructor.

Do something like this:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;  // Use the Base class constructor as our own

    // Rest of Derived class...
};
```

Then define a *single* variable of the `Derived` class:

```
Derived d(2, 3);
d.print();
```

---

Node that with your current code, you attempt to define two *different* and *unrelated* variables `b` and `d`.

Answer (score 0):

`Derived` doesn't have a default constructor so you can't do

```cpp
Derived d;
```

You could add one though - and bring in the `Base` constructors while you're at it:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    Base() : Base(0, 0) {}  // now Base has a default ctor
    Base(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}

protected:
    int a, b;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;      // and now Derived can also use it
    void print() { std::cout << a * b; }
};
```